# SSH SFTP Only With chroot and command

Tags: ssh, chroot, sftp, sshd, ssh-config

I try to restrict access to SFTP Only with one User Account. After Login there should some commands be executed.Therefore i inserted forcecommmand in my sshd_config:

```
Match group stream
   #ChrootDirectory /home/%u
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand sudo /etc/mountsftp.sh
   #ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

This works fine and my command Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date +"%T,%D")
echo "Login : $now" >> /login.log
sshfs usrl@server:/usbshare1-2 /media/pp -o reconnect -o allow_other -o workaround=all
mount --bind /media/pp/Serien /home/stream/Serien
J=$HOME
#
#exit by calling a shell to open for the ssh session
#internal-sftp
#cp -v /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server $J/bin/
chroot $J /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

is executed. But after the CHROOT its not possible to start the sftp-server, because its not found after chroot. But I need Chroot as well as this sftp-server. Is there any way to accomplish this?

PS: Autofs for the mount is no option, because everything is executed on an vserver without the needed Kernel modules.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the `sftp-server` binary and all its dependencies (`ldd /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server`) to the chroot and you will be able to run it.

Comment: I tried this, my chroot directory got this tree:
`|-- bin
|   |-- bash
|   -- sftp-server
|-- dev
|   -- null
|-- etc
|   |-- hosts
|   |-- ld.so.cache
|   |-- ld.so.conf
|   -- nsswitch.conf
|-- lib
|   -- x86_64-linux-gnu
|       |-- libc.so.6
|       |-- libdl.so.2
|       -- libtinfo.so.5
|-- lib64
|-- mountsftp.sh
|-- Serien`

but i get this error: chroot: failed to run command ‘/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server’: Not a directory

Comment: Please, edit the question with details what you tried. It is not readable in the comments.

Comment: You also probably need to run the command `chroot` with correct path to the binary you copied: `chroot $J $J/sftp-server